# Cannot retrieve the number of affected rows of a PDOStatement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Using PDO connection to MySQL.
I can't retrieve the number of affected rows for an "INSERT INTO" query

```
$sql = 'insert into ... ';
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$q = $q->execute();
echo ( $q->rowCount() );
echo ( $q->affectedRows() );
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object.
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function affectedRows() on a non-object.

The record is inserted successfully but I can't check it because it won't return anything.
What is wrong?

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be overwriting the `$q` variable when you call [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.execute.php); it returns a boolean value.  Simply remove the assignment when calling the `execute` method:

```
$q->execute();
```

There is also no method called `affectedRows` in PDOStatement.  [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.rowcount.php) should be all that you need:

> `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

Comment: Thanks! $dbh I meant. rowCount() worked. But not affectedRows(). When should I use affectedRows() then?